# Action now allowed with Plugin Authake in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, authentication

I've a small problem with Rules in Authake Plugin and I want to know if anyone passed for the same problem or can help me.
Authake Plugin is really nice and saved me a lot of work.
My problem is with the rules, I want to allow user to access the following actions:

```
/authake/user/*
/register
/login
/logout
/lost-password
/verify(/)?*
/pass(/)?*
/profile
/denied
/doencas
/desordens/index
/desordens/view
/profissionais/index
/profissionais/view
/nacionais/index
/nacionais/view
/instituicos/index
/instituicos/view
```

The permissions works for the most of actions, except for

> `/profissionais/index
>   /profissionais/view
>   /instituicos/index
>   /instituicos/view`

I have configured the routes in routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/register', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'register'));
    Router::connect('/login', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'login'));
    Router::connect('/rest_login', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller' => 'rest_user', 'action' => 'login'));
    Router::connect('/logout', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'logout'));
    Router::connect('/lost-password', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'lost_password'));
    Router::connect('/verify/*', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'verify'));
    Router::connect('/pass/*', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'pass'));
    Router::connect('/profile', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'index'));
    Router::connect('/denied', array('plugin'=>'authake', 'controller'=>'user', 'action'=>'denied'));
    Router::connect('/doencas', array('plugin'=>'', 'controller'=>'desordens', 'action'=>'index'));
    Router::connect('/profissionais', array('plugin'=>'','controller'=>'profissionais'));
    Router::connect('/desordens', array('plugin'=>'','controller'=>'desordens'));
    Router::connect('/instituicos', array('plugin'=>'','controller'=>'instituicos'));
    Router::connect('/sinonimos', array('plugin'=>'','controller'=>'sinonimos'));
    Router::connect('/dadosNacionais', array('plugin'=>'','controller'=>'dadosNacionais'));
    Router::connect('/referencias', array('plugin'=>'','controller'=>'referencias'));
```

Just the actions of that 2 controllers (instituicos and professinais) don't work.
I search in many sites, I looked at the MySQL table(Authake_rules), the files in Cake many times and I can't find some reason to this happen.
And I have others 2 actions I didn't put on the list of allowed actions and this actions is allowed for public access.
I don't know if this is a Bug in Plugin or I forget something, I have read many times the Docs in the GitHub project: https://github.com/mtkocak/authake looking for something but I didn't find anything to help me with this.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: I figure out the problem, its because i put one function beforeFilter() inside in this controller who i found the problem...so i think this was overriding the beforeFIlter() function of the Authake plugin, after i remove the function (Because was in blank) everything starts to work fine. o//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours trying i discover a possible solution, i just put a new route for each controller with a alias, for example in Profissionais Controller i put:

```
/profissionais/index
/profissionais/view/
/especialistas
```

`/especialistas` it's a alias created for the Profissionais Controller, with this everything works fine!! I create one alias for each others controllers and now its work !!!